Kivy Buildozer error base.dm not found kivy icon no access errno 13
Python: 3.12.5
OS: Arch Linux
Buildozer: 1.5.0
Kivy: 2.3.0
I'm trying to package my application into an APK, it crashes on launch because it can't find base.dm, and I have no clue what base.dm is, I'm not referencing it anywhere. It can't access the kivy icon because access is denied, even though it's in its owned folder. I've tried different buildozer versions, buildozer android clean, different kivy versions, different android api versions, everything.
buildozer.spec: https://pastebin.com/deiWJibD
error log: https://pastebin.com/K6M5cjA4
imports:
import threading
import logging
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions, check_permission
from jnius import autoclass
import hashlib
from android.content import Intent
from android.net import Uri


You can solve it with adding the extension to include into the package bundle, the error log: 09-12 16:12:26.142 11236 11236 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~ql2Jq9YfNRCGbNIldqZjGQ==/org.test.beaware-8Kne713KgRgZxFIBdoRMTw==/base.dm': No such file or directory suggests that your app or python looks for the file base.dm but No such file or directory, and your buildozer.spec file includes only the file extensions source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,txt one more is missing the dm extension (assuming this is a file).
If the file base.dm is not supposed to exists at the beginning, you can manage the error adding the lines to your code:
import os
if os.path.isfile("base.dm")==False: pass


I don't know what base.dm is, I'm not referencing it anywhere, nor do I want it. I think it's something that's referenced in the actual buildozer or kivy module.

True, try creating a new folder (empty folder) and copy the main.py script, try adding "dm" in extensions in buildozer, Kivy 2.3.0 does internally some shutil operations that do not make sense when unzipping the bundle, there is a possibility many tests have been performed in the current folder and a module or library tries to read the file from other sources which trigger the error after compiling (meaning the Desktop version won't show the error because it utilizes the native python installation but the mobile utilizes the buildozer bundle).

I've re-created the venv and .buildozer in a new folder, only installing what was absolutely necessary, which is kivy,buildozer, and cython, and I'm still getting the same errors. base.dm is not found, and it's trying to access an icon, which it doesn't have permissions for. log: https://pastebin.com/8Yc6Vqwq @jbsidis

Try deleting the .buildozer folder again where the main.py script is, then edit the buildozer.spec file and change the requirements: requirements = kivy==2.3.0,kivymd==0.104.1,python3,pyjnius,plyer,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,pip,Image,PIL,android then try creating a empty base.dm file just for the app to find it and add the dm extension so the file can exists

unfortunately it didn't work... logs: https://pastebin.com/KsdzqFgA
